# Change WPF ComboBox displayed Text

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox bound to an ObservableCollection<> collection.  There's 7 objects in the collection which are a class that has a string to display and a DateTime.  The first item in the collection is blank and when the user drops down the list they see the text selections (Today, Tomorrow, Today @ Noon, Today @ Midnight...).  The user picks one and then I set the text of the first item to a computed value (28-Jan-2016 6:00AM).  This all works fine on the ComboBox closed event.

However I then have another place where the user can tweak the hours or minutes part.  Say to change the hour 6 to 9.  I then update the text of the first object in the collection.  Now I want to get the closed ComboBox control to update what it is currently displaying.

The first issue I see is that what I'm changing is "inside" the collection so INotifyPropertyChanged isn't going to help.  Then I realize that I'm changing the contents of the existing object so I don't see how the ComboBox would even know to update.

My thought at the moment is that I'm going down the wrong path altogether and there's a better pattern to sue.  Either that or there's some simple "reset" the ComboBox mechanism that I haven't found.

Answer (score 0):

Your Object must implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged
Please have a look [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

as for your method I believe you have to arrange your ComboBoxes in a way that when you chose an option in a ComboBox the next ones should consider that and exclude the options which don't go with the selected choices before